# Fragment is not being replaced immediately

Tags: android, fragment

I use a fragment with different data several times, but sometimes fragment is not replace immediately.

```
  FunVideoFragment.prepareFun
  (
       videoSuggestionListNew.get(position).getEnTitle(),
       videoSuggestionListNew.get(position).getFaTitle(),
       videoSuggestionListNew.get(position).getLink(),
       videoSuggestionListNew.get(position).getEnText(),
       videoSuggestionListNew.get(position).getImage(),
       String.valueOf(videoSuggestionListNew.get(position).getTopicCode()),
       videoSuggestionListNew.get(position).getContentCode(),
       videoSuggestionListNew.get(position).getCategory(),
       videoSuggestionListNew.get(position).getTextPartOfSpeech(), "fun"
  );

Log.e("parimah","start2");

Helper.fragmentInflater(new FunVideoFragment(), MainActivity.mContext);
```

and code of fragment:

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.e("parimah","start3");

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fun_video, container, false);
    initializing();

    // some function

    return rootview;
}

   public static void prepareFun
        (String enTitle, String faTitle, String url, String subtitle, String imageVideo, String topicCode, String contentCode, String category, String vocab, String type) {
    videoEnTitle = enTitle;
    videoFaTitle = faTitle;
    videoUrl = url;
    videoSubtitle = subtitle;
    videoImage = imageVideo;
    downloadedVideoName = topicCode + contentCode;

    videoTopicCode = topicCode;
    videoContentCode = contentCode;
    videoCategory = category;
    videoType = type;
    videoVocab = vocab;
}
```

this have sometimes delay .for example :

```
2020-05-16 18:45:59.576 11729-11729/ir.barmanrayan.tikkaa E/parimah: start2
2020-05-16 18:46:07.729 11729-11729/ir.barmanrayan.tikkaa E/parimah: start3
```

How can delete this delay and show fragment immediately?

Comment: @Zain "start2" is before initializing();

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code: Firstly, I suggest that you should use a more appropriate logging method from the `android.util.Log` class instead of the `Log#e` method which logs a message to the logcat with a level of an error such that it is easier to categorise. Secondly, could you include the `prepaeFun` method code from your fragment?

Comment: @Edric .I add `prepareFun` code